# What is the Markdown equivalent to LaTeX's description environment?

Tags: list, markdown

Is there a Markdown equivalent to LaTeX's description environment? This gives an author the ability to generate lists where the first word is boldfaced, like this:

[image: description environment]

The LaTeX source would be:

```
\begin{description}
  \item[First] The first item
  \item[Second] The second item
  \item[Third] The third etc \ldots
\end{description}
```

I'd like to replicate this in Markdown so that if I run the Markdown through a tool such as `pandoc` I will get similar results.

Comment: Why is this being flagged as being off-topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Markdown isn't as comprehensive as LaTeX, or [even HTML](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html):

> Markdown’s syntax is intended for one purpose: to be used as a format for *writing* for the web.
>
> Markdown is not a replacement for HTML, or even close to it. Its syntax is very small, corresponding only to a very small subset of HTML tags.

It supports [bulleted and numbered lists](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list), but not defiition lists.

However, you mention using "a tool such as `pandoc`" to process your input file. Pandoc supports inline LaTeX using the `raw_tex` extension:

> ### Extension: raw_tex
>
> In addition to raw HTML, pandoc allows raw LaTeX, TeX, and ConTeXt to be included in a document. Inline TeX commands will be preserved and passed unchanged to the LaTeX and ConTeXt writers. Thus, for example, you can use LaTeX to include BibTeX citations:
>
> ```
> This result was proved in \cite{jones.1967}.
> ```
>
> Note that in LaTeX environments, like
>
> ```
> \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}\hline
> Age & Frequency \\ \hline
> 18--25  & 15 \\
> 26--35  & 33 \\
> 36--45  & 22 \\ \hline
> \end{tabular}
> ```
>
> the material between the begin and end tags will be interpreted as raw LaTeX, not as markdown.
>
> Inline LaTeX is ignored in output formats other than Markdown, LaTeX, and ConTeXt.

So simply including your LaTeX `description` environment and running Pandoc with the `raw_tex` extension should give you the result you want.

You may have to specify the source format manually, e.g. by using something like `-f markdown_strict+raw_tex` in your command.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the latest version of Pandoc (ver 2.0+), you can use [the definition lists notation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#definition-lists), as shown below. This would be much easier.

```
First

: The first item

Second

: The second item

Third

: The third etc
```