# Bookdown definition/description list?

Tags: r, bookdown

How can I achieve a definition/description list in Bookdown?  I have the following at the top of a chapter:

```
# Chapter 2

hello?

\describe{
  \item{Q_t(a)}{estimated value of action $a$ at time step $t$}
  \item{A_t}{action selected at time step $t$}
  \item{R_t}{reward at time step $t$}
}
```

In the rendered output, I only see the `hello?` output, the `\describe...` output is not shown at all.

I also tried a `\begin{describe}...\end{describe}` block, and a `\begin{description}...\end{description}` block, with the same effect.

Thanks.

**Edit** - to be clear: `\describe{` is [special R documentation format](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html#text-formatting), `\begin{description}` is [LaTeX](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures), and `\begin{describe}` is me flailing around trying to find something that works.

Comment: While you can [convert your HTML book to PDF](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/latex.html), usually you'd render your bookdown document to HTML. You have access to [certain `LaTeX` commands through `MathJax`](http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm), however the more general `LaTeX` environments (like `itemize`, `enumerate`, `description`) are not  supported. You also seem to mix up LaTeX and non-LaTeX code; for example `Q_t(a)` will throw an error within a LaTeX(-like) environment.

Comment: After some searching, this seems to be a duplicate of (or at least very closely related to) [What is the Markdown equivalent to LaTeX's description environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057101/what-is-the-markdown-equivalent-to-latexs-description-environment).

Comment: @MauritsEvers why would `Q_t(a)` throw an error in a LaTeX environment, it's perfectly valid LaTeX, isn't it?

Comment: **EDIT** sorry, I see - `Q_t(a)` is not valid in a LaTeX *text* environment, indeed.  Only valid in a LaTeX *math* environment.